# Vaadin 14 Grid autoWidth with wrap content

Tags: css, grid, vaadin

I`m working with Vaadin 14 and i have a problem with sizing cells in Grid.
I would like to set autowidth on all columns to reduce size of column with small content size, but for long i want to achive max size of column without horizontall scroll ( i want to see all columns at once) and when it would exceed size of the table then i would like to wrap conten inside this column.

When i'm setting autoWidth for all columns then my long conten is shown in one line and i must scrolling horizontally to see other columns.
When i`m setting

`grid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_COMPACT,GridVariant.LUMO_WRAP_CELL_CONTENT);`
then my long column has this same size but with multi-line content as other columns with short content. Other columns are too long for their content.

I can`t set width separately for each column couse i dont know how many columns will be in the Grid and which column will have long or short content.

Comment: This feels to me like something that sounds simple, but is actually very difficult to achieve. Once you start wrapping columns, they suddenly need a lot less width, and you would have to recalculate everything again. And how does it decide which columns to wrap, and which not to? I think the layouting just doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s what I would try:

- Use the LUMO_WRAP_CELL_CONTENT variant
- For all other columns than the one with long content, set autoWidth and flexGrow=0
- For the column with long content, set width to what you want as max-width and set flexGrow=1

Comment: but i dont know how many columns will be in table and how much space will they take and how many columns will have long content + i want to let user to resize over default width. I want to all column on first sight but still let user to resize them above width of the grid in the panel. I have one more question, is it possible to disable horizontal scroll and instead of it when i`m resizing one column then other columns would change their size to fit in width of grid without adding horizontal scroll/ just moving next columns farther of the table?

Comment: You can try setting the width of all columns to zero, to allow them to shrink below the default 100px width. But once the user resizes a column, that column and all columns before it will get a fixed width, and won't shrink/grow any longer when you resize other columns. You could try listening to the `column-resize` event, reset the widths and adjust flexGrow to match the width distribution.